# how to change the right control key in a super/hyper modifier in emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, key-binding

I'd like to change the right <kbd>control</kbd> key along into a "super" modifier and right <kbd>alt</kbd> key into the "alt" modifier (not the Meta) in Solaris and Linux (as I know how to do that in Windows using AutoHotKey). I know how to do this:

```
(define-key local-function-key-map (kbd "<rwindow>") 'event-apply-super-modifier
```

But I don't know how to specify the *right* <kbd>control</kbd> key or *right* <kbd>alt</kbd> key (which are more convenient to type than the Windows keys). If that can be done straight in emacs (and avoid AutoHotKey in Windows as well) that would be great. Otherwise I'd like to know what can achieve in Solaris and Linux the same think that AutoHotKey does.

Comment: What do you mean by "right left alt key"? I am assuming you mean either right *or* left. Can you edit your question to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this in Emacs. As far as I know, the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are treated the same. For some OSes, there's an option to change the keysym for <kbd>R-Alt</kbd> but I don't know of one for X Windows. Note that you can use the `x-alt-keysym` variable to change the keysym for *both* <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.

You can change the modifiers bound to each key in X Windows using `xmodmap`. The Arch Wiki [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) covers its use. Basically:

- Type `xmodmap -pm` to print a list of modifiers and the keys assigned to them, eg.

  ```
      shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
      lock
      control     Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
      mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
      mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86) ....
  ```
- Then create a file that clears and rebinds the modifiers you want to change. Eg. to change <kbd>R-Ctrl</kbd> to `super`, this should work:

  ```
      clear super
      add super = Super_L Super_R Control_R
      clear control
      add control = Control_L
  ```
- To handle, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys, you could use:

  ```
      clear meta
      add meta = Alt_L
  ```

  That should cause Emacs to find the existing `meta` modifier and stop treating the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys as `meta` by default. Then the <kbd>R-Alt</kbd> key will be available as an `alt` modifier for use in Emacs (and the <kbd>L-Alt</kbd> as `meta`). I've never tried this.

  If that doesn't work, you'll have to pick an unused modifier to bind <kbd>R-Alt</kbd> to, eg. `hyper`. Then you could use that in Emacs bindings.
- You can activate the changes saving your file as `~/.Xmodmap` and running

  ```
  xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
  ```

  In many desktop environment, `~/.Xmodmap` will be automatically run at startup. If not, you'll have to run it in your `~/.xinitrc` file:

  ```
  if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
      xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
  fi
  ```

Comment: xev shows different symbols (here at least) for left/right control, alt keys.  It has done that for every system I have used with X that has those physical keys.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey: Different keysyms? Different to mine, or different to each other? Mine are different for the left and right key of each type as well. They're assigned to the same modifiers, though. `Ctrl_L` (FFE3) and `Ctrl_R` (FFE4) are assigned to the `control` modifier. `Alt_L` (FFEA) and `Alt_R` (FFE9) are assigned to the `mod1` modifier.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I have X available on the linux machines (I'll be using them over ssh) - which I failed to mention - but I appreciate your answer.